# Want to add an array of objects inside a nested object: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need to add an array of objects to another object whose structure has been shown below.

Here `arr` is the array of objects that needs to be added to "dest" object.

Help would be appreciated.

Structure:

```
var arr = [
    { field: "state", value: "value2"},
    { field: "city", value: "value3"}
];
```

This array of objects needs to be added to an object of following structure:

```
var dest = {
    "topic": "test",
    "filter": {
        "sequence": [
            {
                "field": "country",
                "value": "value1",
            }
        ]
    },
    "order": [
        {
            "field": "field1",
            "order": "backward"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would want to add the fields of `arr` inside `sequence` so that result would be something like this:

```
var dest = {
    "topic": "test",
    "filter": {
        "sequence": [
            {
                "field": "country",
                "value": "value1",
            },
            {
                "field": "state",
                "value": "value2",
            },
            {
                "field": "city",
                "value": "value3",
            }
        ]
    },
    "order": [
        {
            "field": "field1",
            "order": "backward"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `dest.filter.sequence.push(...arr)`?

Comment: `dest.filter.sequence = dest.filter.sequence.concat(arr)`??

Comment: @AbanaClara, that needs an assignment of the returned new array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Can I know the reason for spreading arr?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt if you push the array in `.sequence`, then you have `[ {}, [] ]` as its contents -- which is wrong. Spreading is the right way to do it

Comment: @NinaScholz Its giving 3 as result?

Comment: yes. it's the new length of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `forEach()` you can do it.

```js
var arr = [
    { field: "state", value: "value2"},
    { field: "city", value: "value3"}
];

var dest = {
    "topic": "test",
    "filter": {
        "sequence": [
            {
                "field": "country",
                "value": "value1",
            }
        ]
    },
    "order": [
        {
            "field": "field1",
            "order": "backward"
        }
    ]
}

arr.forEach(function (item) {
    dest.filter.sequence.push(item)
});

console.log(dest)
```

Also ES6 [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator can be used to merge

```js
var arr = [
    { field: "state", value: "value2"},
    { field: "city", value: "value3"}
];

var dest = {
    "topic": "test",
    "filter": {
        "sequence": [
            {
                "field": "country",
                "value": "value1",
            }
        ]
    },
    "order": [
        {
            "field": "field1",
            "order": "backward"
        }
    ]
}
    
dest.filter.sequence.push(...arr)

console.log(dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use below code to insert array into object.

```
        arr.forEach( function(value, index, array) {
            dest.filter.sequence.push(value);
        });
```